# Criar sessão ao fazer requisições ao Web Service

Tags: java, json, web-service, session, servlet

Criei um criei um **Web Service** que traz resultados no formato **JSON** em **java**, mas algumas vezes quando o usuário faz alguma requisição ao Web Service o mesmo trava e interrompe todo o serviço, gostaria de saber se há possibilidade de criar sessões para cada usuário onde se um usuário fazer uma requisição e travar após alguns minutos a sessão e encerrada?

Comment: resolveu seu problema?